# How to restrict UITextField to a defined set of characters and limit the length?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am working on a login and resister view controller. I am limiting usernames to 12 characters and passwords to 16 using :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range   replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

  if(textField==self.userField){

      NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
      return !([newString length] > 12);
    }

    else if(textField==self.passwordField){
        NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        return !([newString length] > 16);

    }

    return YES;

}
```

this works well but I also want to limit it to a set of characters to stop unwanted symbols and also Chinese characters. I want to define this set:

```
#define ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
```

Not sure how to add it to the method above though and get both working. If I was to check for the character set only and not length the code would be:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {
    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS] invertedSet];

    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
}
```

Not sure how to combine them though. Can someone help me please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like (I divided it to function for more readability and easy to scale the conditions)

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    return ([self checkLengthOfString:newString inField:textField] && [self checkCharacter:newString]);
}


// Check Length
- (BOOL)checkLengthOfString:(NSString *)text inField:(UITextField *)textField
{
   if(textField == self.userField)
   {
      return !([text length] > 12);
   }
   else if(textField == self.passwordField)
   {
      return !([text length] > 16);
   }
}

// Check character
- (BOOL)checkCharacter:(NSString *)text
{
    BOOL status        = YES;
    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS] invertedSet];
    NSRange r          = [text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:s];
    if (r.location != NSNotFound)
    {
       status = NO;
    }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: how does the && operator work for these two booleans?

Comment: If both is true, then it will return true else false

Comment: I think the problem is I don't totally understand how the shouldChangeCharactersInRange method works. For the checkLength method these lines: NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
      return !([newString length] > 12);. Could you just clarify what happens here please?

Comment: @Kex: you wrote that in your code, right ? When you type a character the above delegate method will be called and if it returns true the typed character will be showed else discarded. Say you already typed 'Mid' then you are typed 'h'. The delegate method will be called, still the textfield contains 'Mid' only (since the method didn't return) and the string parameter have the 'h' and the position of that character. You are replacing (appending that to the existing textfield.text there) Just put a NSLog there and check textField.text and string when you type each time

Comment: okay think I've got it, just one last thing. Where does range come from? stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range. What is the range that is passed through the method?

Comment: @Kex: That's been handled by iOS itself. Range is for find the position of character (Remember you can type in between of a string, first or last. So we need to identify where we need to append that string)

Comment: got it, understand. Thanks! The code above works too, but need to add shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string to the parameters in the checkLength method and add replacementString:(NSString *)string to the checkCharacter method.

Comment: @Kex: Thanks for the comment, I modified my method

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a regEx to match that chars?

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered, but I had a similar scenario and I found none of the answers on StackOverflow handled the Backspace character.

I needed to limit input into a UITextField to a specific number of AlphaNumeric characters, but be able to enter spaces.

Also, using [textField length] > kMAXNUMCHARS caused a problem: you couldn't backspace once you hit the max number of chars.

So here's my complete solution. It also disallows leading spaces. Trailing spaces are trimmed elsewhere when the value is saved (in my case to a PLIST file)

In my Constants.h file I defined:

```
#define ALLOWED_CHARECTERS @" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
extern const int kMAXUSERNAMELENGTH;
```

then in Constants.m:

```
const int kMAXUSERNAMELENGTH = 9;
```

I define my class as UITextFieldDelegate with the line

```
[self._txtUsername.textField  setDelegate:self];
```

Don't forget to declare the UITextFieldDelegate protocol in your class definiion

```
@interface MyClass : CCNode <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

And finally,

```
    //UITextFiledDelegate Protocol method
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

        //disallow leading spaces. must allow trailing spaces- never know if we'll add another char
        //we trim trailing spaces when we save the TextField value, in our case to  Plist file
        if (range.location == 0 && [string isEqualToString:@" "]) 
            return NO;

        //we use defined ALLOWED_CHARECTERS so we can add chars later, easily. 
        //we could use [NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] if we don't need to allow spaces
        NSCharacterSet *allowedInput = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ALLOWED_CHARECTERS];
        NSArray* arChar = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:allowedInput]; //arChar.count = 1 if 'allowedInput' not in 'string'

        //disallow input if its not a backspace (replacementString paramater string equal @"" if a backspace) AND
        //(disallow input >= kMAXUSERNAMELENGTH chars, OR disallow if not in allowed allowedChar set
        if ( ![string isEqual:@""]  && (  [textField.text length] >= kMAXUSERNAMELENGTH || !([arChar count] > 1)) ) 
             return NO;

        return YES;

    }
```

I hope this helps someone.